# Black screen X cursor

Tags: graphics, xorg

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 the other day and have been setting it up to my liking and loving every minute of it.

Today I came across an article entitled [8 Things To Do After Installing Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/8-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html). So I did the 8 things; just copied and pasted commands.

I rebooted my PC and now all I get after Ubuntu loads is some errors and a black screen with an X cursor that I can move around. I can get to the terminal using Alt + F2 but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Does anyone have a solution or a way to get back the default setting?

Comment: This one? http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/8-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html -So you were coping *all* the commands? If you don't have hybrid graphics #4 is probably what did it.

Comment: yep. exacly the page

Answer (score 0):

To revert the step #4 (which is the most probable that caused the issue), you only need to:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

Obviously you shouldn't do everything told without double checking what it is being done.